# button click event not working after publishing project on server

Tags: asp.net

I have code like below.i Have a little problem with my button click event. It's working properly on my localhost when I run my visual studio debugging, but when I upload files on server this button click event not working.
    below is my .aspx page

```
<div class="apply-job" style="padding-top:10px">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-md-8 ap-form-sec" style="float:left">
                                    <h3 class="font-title">Contact <span>Us</span></h3>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <form class="apply-job-form">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtfirstname" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="First Name"></asp:TextBox>

                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtsub" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Subject"></asp:TextBox>

                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtadd" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Home Address"></asp:TextBox>

                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtstate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="State"></asp:TextBox>

                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtphone" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Phone"></asp:TextBox>

                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtemail" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Email"></asp:TextBox>

                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>


                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtlastname" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Last Name"></asp:TextBox>

                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                             <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:6px">
                                                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtmsg" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Message" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>

                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtcity" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="City"></asp:TextBox>

                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtzip" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Zip code"></asp:TextBox>

                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>



                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                     <div class="text-content center">
                                                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                         <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit Your Application" CssClass="btn btn-default" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>

                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And below is my .aspx.cs page.I used System.net.mail namespace for sending mail.i think the problem is when I click on the button it doesn't fires the click event of the button and do the rest or i think may be some css conflicts.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void clearcontrol()
    {
        txtfirstname.Text = "";
        txtlastname.Text = "";
        txtcity.Text = "";
        txtstate.Text = "";
        txtemail.Text = "";
        txtphone.Text = "";
        txtsub.Text = "";
        txtadd.Text = "";
        txtmsg.Text = "";
        txtzip.Text = "";


    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient()
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                //UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("shreehe741@gmail.com", "**********"),
                EnableSsl = true
            };
            MailAddress esender = new MailAddress("shreehe741@gmail.com");
            mail.From = esender;
            MailAddress erec = new MailAddress("shreehe741@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add(erec);
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Body = "<html> " +
                          "<head> " +
                          "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' /> " +
                          "<title> Appointment </title> " +
                          "</head> " +
                          "<body> " +
                           "<table width='400px' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2' > " +
                          "<tr> " +
                          "<td><h4>Applicant name is</h4> " + txtfirstname.Text +" "+txtlastname.Text+ "</td> " +

                          "</tr>" +
                          "<tr> " +

                          "<td><h4>Subject of application is</h4>" + txtsub.Text + "</td> " +
                          "</tr>" +
                           "<tr> " +
                          "<td><h4>Address of applicant name is</h4> " + txtadd.Text + " ," + txtcity.Text+","+txtstate.Text +","+txtzip.Text+ "</td> " +

                          "</tr>" +

                          "<tr>" +
                          "<td><h4>Contact details are given as below </h4> </td> " +
                          "</tr>" +
                          "<tr>" +
                          "<td><h5>Phone number is</h5> " + txtphone.Text + "</td> " +
                          "<td><h5>Email id is</h5> " + txtemail.Text + "</td> " +
                          "</tr>" +
                           "<tr>" +
                          "<td><h4>Message from user </h4>" + txtmsg.Text + "</td> " +
                          "</tr>" +

                           " </table> " +
                          " </body> " +
                          " </html>";


            mail.Subject = "Appointment";
            smtp.Send(mail);
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Your appiontment saved')</script>");
            clearcontrol();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Error :" + ex.Message + "');</script>");
        }
    }
```

I'm fighting with this issue for last 4 days,but still i can't able to find what i'm missing.Even i don't get any exception message after clicking on button on server..

Comment: Is there any javascript or jquery error?

Comment: No.may be not,because it works fine in localhost without any error.problem is occurring at server side.

Comment: @shahharshil try to see in console in the browser are you getting any error?

Comment: i resolved issue.in place of Response.write i kept label and it works fine.so i removed  Response.write.